# Avoid others to make requests to URL and modify users data [DJANGO]

Tags: django, request

in my question I mentioned django, but this is a general question over the user-interaction mechanism with the backend. I'm developing iOS application and, for instance, I want to let the user to update the email address therefore my backend is:

```
class UpdateEmail(APIView):
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer

    def put(self, request):
        user_id = request.data.get('id')
        new_email = request.data.get('new_email').lower()

        User.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(email=new_email)
        return Response('OK')
```

As you can see I made a put request of this type:

```
{
   "id":user_id_logged_in_mobile_device_stored_locally,
   "email":new_email
}
```

My question is, how can I avoid others from making a PUT request and modify some user's informations? Maybe this isn't the correct approach to the problem.

Comment: I don't see how other users would update some one else's information here? `user_id = request.user.id` would give you the current user's id and you perform an update on that user only by using `User.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(email=new_email)`

Comment: yeah you are right, but if you make a PUT request using a random id?

Comment: I don't understood, I'm using it to set new email???

Comment: `request.user.id` != `request.data.get('id')`. `request.user.id` would give you the id of the current **logged in / authenticated** user it does not give you the id that you have sent as put parameters. Don't even send the id in the parameters and you will see.

Comment: ok ok yes, but this id is not defined, as I logged in in another page and the in update-email the request.user is Anonymous? Why this happen?

Comment: In my app I've a login page, and when the user login i call authenticated and login, but then, when i call update-email, the request.user is undefined. I've made a mistake writing the question